# strftime force output in same local timezone

Tags: c, strftime, strptime

My current computer gives the time with CET:

```
$ date
Mon Dec  1 21:31:41 CET 2014
```

However my locale is en_US:

```
$ locale | grep -i time
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
```

I would like to format an epoch string with C to my current local time zone, but I don't know how to tell strptime to change the default local:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int
main(void)
{
   struct tm tm;
   char buf[255];

   memset(&tm, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
   strptime("1412200800", "%s", &tm);
   strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%c %Z", &tm);
   puts(buf);
   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The man page states that it formats the time according to the locale, but it seems to ignore my setting:

```
 $ export LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8
 $ locale | grep -i time
LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8
 $ ./a.out 
Thu Oct  2 00:00:00 2014 CEST
```

What I expect is:

```
Wed Thu Oct  1 22:00:00 2014 CET
```

#### update

OK, so I completely removed `%s` and tried the following approach, but still no success:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int
main(void)
{
   struct tm *tim;
   setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
   char buf[255];
   time_t c;

   c = strtoul("1412200800", NULL, 0);
   tim = localtime(&c);
   strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%c" , tim);
   puts(buf);
   printf("%s %s\n", tzname[0], tzname[1]);
   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The output is still now what I'd expect:

```
gcc strptime_test.c && ./a.out 
Thu 02 Oct 2014 12:00:00 AM CEST
CET CEST
```

#### update 2, the solution:

Instead of using `localtime(&c);` I now use:

```
tim = gmtime(&c);
strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%c" , tim);
```

Which give the desired behaviour:

```
Wed 01 Oct 2014 10:00:00 PM GMT
```

Comment: I think you are actually asking about `strftime`

Comment: @MattMcNabb, yes you are right. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is using a non-standard glibc extension to [strptime](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html); `%s` is the number of seconds since epoch.

According to [Epoch Converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/), `1412200800` is `Wed, 01 Oct 2014 22:00:00 GMT` so your program is behaving correctly.  However, it's unclear whether epoch seconds are to be taken in UTC, or in your local timezone, so as loreb notes in comments you may also need to call a time-zone conversion function.

You will have to make a decision as to whether times (i.e. contents of `time_t` and `struct tm` objects) in your program are times in UTC, or local times.

I would suggest the following fix: replace `strptime` with

```
time_t c = 1412200800;
tm = *gmtime(&c);
```

The other function that might be used here instead of `gmtime` is `localtime`.

---

BTW I think you are mixing up locales and timezones: "locale" means the way that the time is formatted; for example the default might be:

```
Sun Oct  1 00:00:00 2014
```

but the locale-formatted version would be:

```
Sun, Oct 01, 2014 12:00:00 AM
```

Time-zones and locales are different things. (One locale may span multiple timezones, and one timezone may contain multiple locales).

NB. in C, the default locale is the C locale, not the system one. To read locale from environment variables, do:

```
#include <locale.h>

// in main()
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

Comment: http://www.catb.org/esr/time-programming/ has a nice summary of the current situation - a sad, sad mess.

Comment: @loreb yeah it ain't pretty

Comment: @MattMcNabb, Your solution does not work unfortunately (I am using Linux if that matters)

Comment: I understand the program works "as expected", but the question is how to I print the string with CET instead of CEST time formating?

Comment: Does not work - as I meant, but thank to a 3rd and 4rt  reading of your answer I found the solution. So I'll accept it. Thanks for the discussion.

Comment: Your timezone is CET  ; within that there is CEST and CEDT depending on whether daylight time is active

Comment: Partially, it was not clear because of my original intent. I wanted my date formatting to match the one in MongoDB, which is represente in GMT. So my original title is a bit hmm quirky.